# Searching All Subscribers using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to search ALL Subscribers on the basis of Subscriberkey and fetch a profile attribute 'ExternalId'

What AMPScript I can write for that? I don't think Lookup function works on All Subscribers.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Correct - All subscribers is a list. You need to use the API Ampscript functions detailed [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/).

Specifically, you are looking for InvokeRetrieve.  There is example code for pull a subscriber from a list with a simpleFilterPart.

Comment: Hi David, I read through it but not sure how I will be able to use it. Is it possible for you to share the AMPScript?